# Sort by specific column

Tags: sorting, vim

If I have a text file with several tab-separated columns like this:

```
1  foo  bar
3  bar  foo
```

How would I sort based on the second or third column?

I read something like using `:'<,'>!sort -n -k 2` in visual mode or `:sort /.*\%2v/`, but none of these commands seem to work.

Comment: What version of _vim_ are you using? And what does "none of these commands seem to work" exactly mean? Is there any error-message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built in [`sort`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3asort) command.

To sort by the second tab delimited column you can use `:sort /[^\t]*\t/` to sort the second column.
To sort the third column you can use `:sort /[^\t]*\t\{2}/`

Generally just replace the number with the column number minus 1. (ie index columns with first column being index 0)

Comment: sweet. I just used the same principle to sort a list of email addresses by domain name. i.e. `:sort /[^@]*@/`

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it doesn't seem to be possible with the use of visual blocks inside the same file and/or with one command because `:ex` is linewise, i.e. <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>+ `selection` + `:'<,'>sort` would just sort the whole line either way.

A somewhat hacky "solution" would be to select whatever you want to sort with a visual block, sort it in another window and apply the changes to your original file. Something like this:

<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> + `selection` + <kbd>x</kbd> + `:tabnew` + <kbd>p</kbd> + `:sort` + <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> + `:q` + <kbd>`[P</kbd> (align paste)

**Source**: [Barry Arthur - Sort Me A Column](http://of-vim-and-vigor.blogspot.no/2013/04/sort-me-column.html) (bairui from #vim@freenode).

Answer (score 0):

The external `sort`, called via `:'<,'>!sort -k 2` does work. Only if the `-n` flag (for numeric sorting) is given but the column you want to use is non-numeric, the result is not as expected. So to use the external `sort`, just drop `-n` in your example.

*Remark:* Also `:'<,'>sort /.*\%2v/` does work for me.